# Datomic Jetty Compiler Exception (in compojure-api project)

Tags: clojure, datomic

Clojure newbie here. I'm trying to integrate datomic into a `compojure-api` project. There is a clash on jetty, so based on the [docs](https://docs.datomic.com/cloud/troubleshooting.html#dependency-conflict), my `project.clj` looks like this, which makes it work now when I do `lein ring server`

```
 (defproject dice-api "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
   :description "FIXME: write description"
   :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.8.0"]
                  [metosin/compojure-api "1.1.11"]
                  [com.datomic/client-pro "0.8.28"
                   :exclusions [org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-client
                               org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-http
                               org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-util]]]
   :ring {:handler dice-api.handler/app}
   :uberjar-name "server.jar"
   :profiles {:dev {:dependencies [[javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api "3.1.0"]]
                   :plugins [[lein-ring "0.12.0"]]}})
```

However, I can't play with datomic in the repl now(and probably, wont' work when I call it in my compojure-api endpoint).

```
➜  dice-api lein repl
...
user=> (require '[datomic.client.api :as d])
nil
user=> (def local-cfg {:server-type :peer-server
  #_=>                  :access-key "blahblahblah"
  #_=>                  :secret "blahblahblah"
  #_=>                  :endpoint "localhost:8998"})
#'user/local-cfg
user=> (defn client [cfg]
  #_=>   (d/client cfg))
#'user/client
user=> (def conn (d/connect (client local-cfg) {:db-name "hello"}))

CompilerException java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpClient, compiling:(cognitect/http_client.clj:1:1)
```

How can I integrate `datomic` and `compojure-api`?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't use the exact combination you have, but it may help to clone [the Tupelo Datomic project](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo-datomic).  It is a standalone project using Datomic Free and is completely self-contained.  Clone the repo and you should be able to run `lein test` like so:

```
~/tupelo-datomic > 
~/tupelo-datomic > lein clean
~/tupelo-datomic > lein test

WARNING: find already refers to: #'clojure.core/find in namespace: tupelo-datomic.core, being replaced by: #'tupelo-datomic.core/find
*clojure-version* => {:major 1, :minor 10, :incremental 0, :qualifier nil}

lein test tst.tupelo-datomic._bootstrap

-------------------------------
   Clojure 1.10.0    Java 11
-------------------------------

lein test tst.tupelo-datomic.bond

lein test tst.tupelo-datomic.bond-query

lein test tst.tupelo-datomic.core

lein test tst.tupelo-datomic.find

lein test tst.tupelo-datomic.functionality

lein test tst.tupelo-datomic.quick-start
:using-local

Ran 17 tests containing 110 assertions.
0 failures, 0 errors.
~/tupelo-datomic >
```

Since it is completely standalone, you should be able to add in whatever web framework you wish.

Comment: Can I do it the other way round? Add `tupelo-datomic` in the `project.clj` of my existing project? I tried and I get:
`Retrieving org/clojure/clojure/1.7.0/clojure-1.7.0.jar from central
Could not find artifact com.datomic:datomic-pro:jar:0.9.5359 in central (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/)...`

Comment: Try deleting all references to datomic in your `project.clj`

Comment: There was only one reference i.e. to `tupelo-datomic` in my `project.clj`. I'll try again but I have moved on to `pedestal` which plays nicely with `datomic`. Thank you for your help :).

Comment: I meant this: [com.datomic/client-pro "0.8.28" ...].   As an aside, I prefer pedestal as my first choice as well.